# I have a very simple XML & XML schenm which is throwing following error during parsing

Tags: xml

Errors in the XML document:

```
13: 11  cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Airport'. No child element is expected at this point.
```

Errors in file xml-schema:

```
10: 54  s4s-att-not-allowed: Attribute 'maxoccurs' cannot appear in element 'element'.
```

[XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKSpM.png)
[XML schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBOmV.png)

Comment: And both of your image links are to xml files, neither is to an xsd file. You should also show your actual XML and XST text files here, not as images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a typo: `maxoccurs` has to be `maxOccurs`, see [XML Schema Part 0: Primer Second Edition](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#attribute-maxOccurs).

Change your XSD and both errors should be resolved.